# Substring PHP cuts accents formatting

Tags: php, utf-8, substring

I'm facing an issue while executing this code with an utf-8 charset
    substr($row['titol'], 0, 50)

As soon as I encounter a letter with an accent in the last position of the string (or it seems like that) where I cut, it loses the "character information" for that accent printing me an "?" instead of the proper letter.

Ie: If my cutting position ends in "... somethingà" it would show "... something?"

[as you can see, the accent is in the last char and gets weridly treated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvlSm.jpg)

[here I deleted part of the title and it shows just fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQJKh.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php).

replace your code portion

> substr($row['titol'], 0, 50)

to

```
mb_internal_encoding(“UTF-8”)    // Optional
mb_substr($row['titol'], 0, 50)
```

Comment: mb_internal_encoding(“UTF-8”) was mandatory in my case, thanks